# How do you signup using UBER API?

Tags: uber-api

I have been checking [this](https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/uberex/Uber_API_Request_Diagrams.pdf) document to find out how to authorize my user but I couldn't see any signup information on the UBER API itself. You can easily login and authorize the existing user but how do you actually sign up using the API? Which API calls to make?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Visit this URL to register and manage your Uber client apps:

https://developer.uber.com/apps

It will prompt for your Uber credentials if you're not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by sign up using the API?
Actually Uber can let you login via Uber's login page and you can input the credentials in the form and submit it; once you pass this authentication, you will get a web page saying if you want to allow your third party app to access user's info; then once you allow or deny it, Uber will redirect to the redirect_url you registered earlier on your app dashboard and send an authorization code to it; then you could use this code to exchange for the access_token for further use.